# Are there any other ways I can write my function for a matlab code?

Tags: matlab, optimization

I'm trying to grab a values from a function with an input of time.
With my code right now, it takes about 10 minutes to evaluate 100 data points, and 20 minutes for 180 data points. I believe what takes the function long to run is the Arterial function. Is there any other ways I can write this code? I'm new to Matlab.

The following are my functions:

```
This function grab a value from predictionvalue function.
  function grabvalues= grabvalue(tfinal,F,f,z,PS)
  tic
  grabvalues=zeros(1,length(tfinal));
  for i=1:length(tfinal)
      grabvalues(i)= predictionvalue(tfinal(i),F,f,z,PS);
  end
  toc
  end
```

This function has three main parts; Arterial function, RK4 function, and Sampling time. The Arterial function takes in shortdata.txt file and linear interpolate the output. The RK4 then use the Arterial function to get the values for Sample times.

```
function  tis_predicted2 = predictionvalue(tfinal,F,f,z,PS)
  %----------------Define Functions-----------%
  %Arterial Function
  load shortdata.txt
  tA=shortdata(:,1);
  AA=shortdata(:,2);
  function output=AF_function_in(tA_input)
  %size(tA);
  xq1=0:0.01:tA_input;
  vq1=interpn(tA,AA,xq1,'linear');
  output=vq1(end);
  %plot(xq1,vq1,'-',tA,AA,'o');
  %set(gca,'XLim',[0 10])
  end

  %Two Compartmental Model Functions
  fP=@(t,I,P) (F/f)*(AF_function_in(t)- P) - (PS/f)*(P-I); % Hct(mv)=0.45
  fI=@(t,I,P)  (PS/z)*(P - I);

  %Initial Condition
  h=0.01;
  N=ceil(tfinal/h);
  t=zeros(1,N);
  P=zeros(1,N);
  I=zeros(1,N);

  %------------------- RK4 Loop-----------------------------------%
  for i=1:N %i=[0, tfinal/h]
      % Update t
      t(i+1)=t(i)+h;
      %Update equation
      k1P = fP(t(i)      , I(i)           ,      P(i)    );
      k1I = fI(t(i)      , I(i)           ,      P(i)    );

      k2P = fP(t(i)+0.5*h, I(i)+ 0.5*k1I*h, P(i)+0.5*k1P*h);
      k2I = fI(t(i)+0.5*h, I(i)+ 0.5*k1I*h, P(i)+0.5*k1P*h);

      k3P = fP(t(i)+0.5*h, I(i)+ 0.5*k2I*h, P(i)+0.5*k2P*h);
      k3I = fI(t(i)+0.5*h, I(i)+ 0.5*k2I*h, P(i)+0.5*k2P*h);

      k4P = fP(t(i)+h    ,I(i)+k3I*h      , P(i)+ k3P*h);
      k4I = fI(t(i)+h    ,I(i)+k3I*h      , P(i)+ k3P*h);

      I(i+1) = (I(i) + h/6 *(k1I + 2*k2I + 2*k3I + k4I));
      P(i+1) = (P(i) + h/6 *(k1P + 2*k2P + 2*k3P + k4P));   
  end
  Tissue_predicted = P*f+I*z;

  %-----------------SAMPLING ---------------------------------------------%
  tdelta=0.835;
  tfinalsub=tfinal+0.000001;
  tSamp=zeros(1,ceil(tfinalsub/tdelta));
  Samp=zeros(1,ceil(tfinalsub/tdelta));
  a(1)=0;
  for d = 1:ceil(tfinalsub/tdelta)-1
      a(d+1)= a(d)+tdelta/h;
      tSamp(d+1)= tSamp(d)+tdelta;
      Samp(d+1)= Tissue_predicted(1,ceil(a(d)+1));   
  end 
  tis_predicted2 = Samp(end);
  end
```

Comment: Use the profiler: https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/profiling-for-improving-performance.html

Comment: I have checked out this. I was wondering if you have any tips on writing these functions differently

Comment: Why aren't you loading shortdata.txt in grabvalue function and passing the data as input? Reading the same file multiple times from disk is long.

Comment: "I have checked out this." What were the results? Where is your function spending the most time? I would say that this post belongs in Code Review, but simply dumping code with no research shown and no explanation is not going to be well-received anywhere.

Comment: @AmritbirSinghGill woah, I should definitely try and do this :)

Comment: @beaker, the most consuming code is the interp code. Also, I'm new to this, so I didn't know where to post this.